# Summing up a specific number of columns in a R dataframe inside for loop and storing it in another dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I have a R dataframe containing sales value for a product in 36 months (from Oct-19 till Sep-22) in 25 branches. I have named it ****metric_alert_sales****:

What I need to do is to take sum of 24 months at a time starting from Oct-19 and store this data in a new dataframe sum_df initialized as all 0. So Oct-21 Column in will store sum(sales from Oct-19 till Sep-21), Nov-21 column will store sum(sales from Nov-19 till Oct-21) and so on till Sep-22.

I have tried to do this using for loop.

```
#initialization of sum_df
sum_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=25,ncol=13))
colnames(sum_df) <- c("branch","oct-21","nov-21","dec-21","jan-22","feb-22","mar-22","apr-22","may-22","jun-22","jul-22","aug-22","sep-22")
sum_df["branch"] <- metric_alert_sales["branch"]
sum_df <- sum_df %>% relocate(branch,.before = NULL) %>% replace(is.na(.),0)
```

#loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mean_df))
{
for (j in 2:ncol(mean_df))
{
sum_df[i,j] <- rowSums(metric_alert_sales[i,j:j+23]) 
}
}
```

But what is happening is that instead of getting sum of sales from Oct-19 till Sep-21 in Oct-21 column in sum_df, I am getting simply the Sep-21 sales value in Oct-21 column. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm commenting as I'm offering you advice rather than a solution; I think you would greatly benefit from embracing the use of 'tidy data' and you can then leverage a rich tool set ('tidyverse') and liberate yourself from the pain of low level manual written loops.  https://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Comment: @NirGraham I understand your point very much. Its just that I started with this approach and I have been trying to resolve this issue for the past one day, so I really want to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: please edit your post then so as to be a reproducible example. you can use tools such as base::dput() or functions from the datapasta package to acheive the sharing of small R objects, in the form of pasteable code.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `metric_alert_sales[i,j:j+23]` as `j:j+23` is pretty much the same as `seq(j,j)+23` or `j+23`.

Comment: @margusl I think you have pin-pointed the issue correctly. Can you please suggest what I can use instead?

Comment: @margusl Hey thanks! I understood what you are saying & resolved it. It should have been j:(j+23) instead of j:j+23

Comment: @avishkar683, sorry for not being more specific before, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

margus has managed to detect the issue. The only mistake I did was to write it as `metric_alert_sales[i,j:j+23]` instead of `metric_alert_sales[i,j:(j+23)]` due to which it was simply being detected as `metric_alert_sales[i,j+23]`.